# Can't render a react-router-dom basic functional component

Tags: reactjs, dom, functional-programming, components, jsx

i'm new to react and started working on a Single page web app with nodejs backend and a simple react with react-bootstrap and react-router-dom front-end, i've learned Functional components and Class Components, everything worked fine for me, until i got this strange error when i try to render a Functional component.

`Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

The error is triggered when i try to render this functional component.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Row, Col, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default (props) => {
    const [clans, setClans] = useState([]);
    
    return(<>
        <div>
            <Row className="pt-4">
                <Col md={12}>
                    <Form.Input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </div>
    </>);
}
```

and here is where i call for it (`component={Clanes}`)

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
//paginas
import Home from './page/Home';
import NuevoClan from './page/NuevoClan';
import Registrarse from './page/Registrarse';
import Clanes from './page/Clanes';

export default ()=>{
    return (<>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact={true} path='/' component={Home}/>
          <Route path='/clanes' component={Clanes}/> // this route can't be rendered
          <Route path='/nuevoclan' component={NuevoClan}/>
          <Route path='/registrarse/:clan?' component={Registrarse}/>
        </Switch>
    </>);
}
```

It should be noted that I have other functional components in the project with the same structure that render without problems. `NuevoClan & Registrarse` uses the same functional component structure. `Home` is a Class component.

i started thinking is a cache problem but i can't find anything related to react cache cleaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i feel ashamed. The problem was the component Form.Input does not exists. so it couldn't be rendered and passed to the Route. then i replaced
`<Form.Input type="text" placeholder="Search" />`
to
`<Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Search" />`
and everything was solved

Answer (score 0):

I would triple check this line

```
import Clanes from './page/Clanes';
```

Also check the file name of Clanes and the extension. Make sure there isn't a space in the name.

Note: The fragment around the div is unnecessary.